# Devise: Load a partial instead of showing a notice for non confirmed members

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

**Is there a way to load a view for no confirmed users that login? 
Default behaviour is to show a notice: " You have to confirm your account before continuing."**

I tried

- overrule the sessions#create method of devise checking for current_user.confirmed_at.blank?
- in the after_singin_path check for current_user.confirmed_at.blank? and render the view instead

My goal is to render a custom view instead of the notice but cannot hook into the right location. Who knows how to accomplish this? thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy the code from the devise github and place in your controllers/devise. then change any action or method you want to.

You may also just extend the devise session controller and override any action you want to.

```
class Abc < Devise::SessionsController
 # this just reopens the class.
 # Remember classes are never "closed" in ruby!
end
```

Comment: yes thats basics, the problem is finding the exact location to overrule

Comment: There is no exact location. You just need to override the create action of session controller and ask your router to use the new action instead of devise default action. Did you set up your routes?                devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }

Answer (score 1):

I like the ruby way of solving this, I guess that in your UsersController after a POST request the user will be returned and signed in using the sign_in(Object) helper Devise provides.

Also I suggest using a confirmed boolean instead of timestamp.

Why not check for the value using an if else statement the ruby way:

```
user.confirmed ? sign_in(user) : render :partial => 'path/partial'
```

Hope this might help you out